# Aplico Switch pero en el caso 0 se ejecutan todos los casos, en el 1 también el default

Tags: java, switch

Al aplicar un Switch case para seleccionar las letras del curp (Propósito de mi programa)que están en función del estado de nacimiento, si ocupo el case 0, me ejecuta también el 1 y el default, y si ejecuto el case 1 sólo el 1 y  el default, pero si me voy directo al default si me ejecuta únicamente el default, ¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar el problema?
sé que aún falta bastante para terminar el programa, peo me ayudarían mucho con ésto.

```
//VARIABLES    
String name, fecha, n1,n2,n3;
char[] curp=new char[13];
int sexo,edo;
//OBTENCIÓN DE DATOS
name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Por favor ingrese su nombre completo comenzando por apellidos","CURP", 3 );
name=name.toUpperCase(); //CONVERSIÓN A MAYÚSCULAS
fecha=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Por favor ingrese su fehca de nacimiento en formato dd-mm-yyyy","CURP", 3 );
sexo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Por favor seleccione su sexo","CURP" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
3,null,new Object[] {"Hombre", "Mujer", "Cancel"},"Cancel");
edo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Por favor seleccione su entidad de nacimiento","CURP" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
3,null,new Object[] {"CDMX"/*DF*/, "Edo. Mex"/*MC*/, "Nuevo León"/*NL*/},"CDMX");
//SEPARACIÓN DEL STRING "name" EN SUBSTRINGS
String[] n=name.split(" ");
n1 = n[0];
n2 = n[1];
n3 = n[2];
switch(edo)
{
    case 0:
        if (sexo==1)
{
System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"M"+"DF");}
else{
System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"H"+"DF");}
    case 1:
        if (sexo==1)
{
System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"M"+"MC");}
else{
System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"H"+"MC");}
    default :
        if (sexo==1)
{
System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"M"+"NL");}
else{
System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"H"+"NL");}
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu lenguaje de programación? Intuyo que es Java, pero siempre debes poner la etiqueta del lenguaje. En cuanto al problema planteado, ten en cuenta que siempre debes poner `break;` al final de cada `case`. [Revisa los ejemplos de la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisas [los ejemplos de la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) podrás  ver con toda claridad que se debe poner `break;` al final de todos los `case`, incluyendo el `default`.

Tu código debería entonces quedar así:

```
switch(edo)
{
    case 0:
        if (sexo==1)
        {
            System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"M"+"DF");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"H"+"DF");
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (sexo==1) 
        {
            System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"M"+"MC");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"H"+"MC");
        }
        break;
    default:
        if (sexo==1) 
        {
            System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"M"+"NL");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n1+" "+fecha+" "+"H"+"NL");
        }
        break;
}
```

Tu código podría todavía simplificarse bastante haciendo una asignación mediante un operador ternario.

Comment: Le agradezco infinitamente, en realidad soy muy nuevo en lo que a programación respecta así que un recordatorio como éste nunca viene mal, nuevamente gracias.